# Passing null as default parameter to avoid using parameter

Tags: c#, null, nullable, null-coalescing-operator

I have created a function to set multiple properties of an object at once. If a certain argument isn't passed to the function then I want to avoid setting/changing it. A simplified example of the cleanest solution I could come up with is this:

```
private void setObjectProperties(MyObject myObject, float param1, bool? param2 = null)
{
    myObject.param1 = param1;
    myObject.param2 = param2 != null ? (bool)param2 : myObject.param2;
}
```

As you can see from this method, if the function is called without `param2` being passed then it will just set `myObject.param2` to itself. (meaning that if nothing is passed to `param2` then the `myObject.param2` property is untouched)

What I have seems a bit messy to me. I'm not sure if it is the 'correct' thing to do. I have thought about method overloading but I thought that this would be even messier; In the real world situation I am passing more than two arguments to be set so I could end up with a lot of overloads.

Am I missing some obvious functionality in C# that allows me to say "Don't set this parameter if nothing is passed to it's corresponding argument"?

Comment: Why method overloading exists then? I would keep it standard so anyone who looks at the code knows what is going on

Comment: @FirstStep If there were 5 properties, you would need 32 overloads to cover all cases.

Comment: isn't it 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5? @rob

Comment: @FirstStep No, because you could set: [not 1, not 2], [1, not 2], [not 1, 2], [1, 2], and so on, for 2 properties.

Comment: What happens if the user wants to pass in `null`? It's a valid value in many cases. That being said, no, there isn't a nice way to do it without a bunch of conditional statements. Whether they're regular if statements, or what you have.

Comment: @Rob It seems like the property is not nullable, so there would not be a way to set it to null. It;s not explicitly stated, but it's implied by the cast to `bool`.

Comment: @DStanley yeah, the property is not nullable. I think your answer is my best bet. Shame, I was hoping for some slick operator to save the day!

Comment: You want your code to do two different things depending on the value of a boolean condition. **Consider using an "if" statement when you're in that situation.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I missing some obvious functionality in C# that allows me to say "Don't set this parameter if nothing is passed to it's corresponding argument"?

Not in a slick operator, but obviously you can do

```
if(param2.HasValue) myObject.param2 = (bool)param2;
```

The only real difference is if you have any logic in your setter it will not be called in this case if the parameter is null.

Answer (score 2):

Try the null-coalescing operator [`??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
private void setObjectProperties(MyObject myObject, float param1, bool? param2 = null, bool? param3 = null)
{
    myObject.param1 = param1;
    myObject.param2 = param2 ?? myObject.param2;
    myObject.param3 = param3 ?? myObject.param3;
}
```

which you can invoke like

```
foo.setObjectProperties(myobj, param1,
       param2: p2, 
       param3: p3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
private void setObjectProperties(float? param1 = null, bool? param2 = null)
{
    if (param1.HasValue) {
      this.param1 = param1.Value;
    }
    if (param2.HasValue) {
      this.param2 = param2.Value;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(); 
myObject.setObjectProperties(param1: 1.2f);
myObject.setObjectProperties(param2: true);
myObject.setObjectProperties(param1: 1.2f, param2: true);
```